# Draw on one JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

How can I paint on a `JPanel` with `paintComponent`? The panel I want to draw on would be in the middle and I don't know how to select it and paint something on it...

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: I'd suggest you start with [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html). There are countless examples of how you might do this, I recommend you take the time to research the issue, try some things and if you run into additional problems as a specific question, as it is, the question is to broad to be answered

Comment: Define "draw". Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working example that show how you can draw "rectangles" on a panel.

Comment: My specific problem refers to drawing on the middle panel, not the drawing process per se.

Comment: I created the Layout in the GUI Designer by Intellij IDEA

Comment: @codor Then you should already have a custom component capable of been drawn to, which you specify to the GUI designer to use (instead of something like a simple `JPanel`), otherwise it's not going to work. How you do this is specific to the GUI editor. This is another reason why we generally recommend against using them

Comment: @codor, `My specific problem refers to drawing on the middle panel, not the drawing process per se` - doesn't make any sense. Drawing IS related to a panel, you can't just randomly draw to any components. So if you know how to draw, then you already know how to draw to a panel. If you don't then you have been given a link which contains 1) working examples 2) a link to the Swing tutorial that show how to do custom painting in general. So you have lots of ready to do. We are not going to write the code for you.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

**Option 1**

You can create a subclass of `JPanel` and override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method and add the drawing logic there.

**Option 2**

Keep track of all components you add to the `JFrame` or in your case `JTabbedPane`. This can be done through adding a `Map<String, JComponent>` to the `JTabbedPane` where each time you add a `JComponent` to the tabbed pane, you add an entry to the `Map`object with some unique key. Then you can call on `map.get(name);` to get the desired `JPanel`

Hope this helps!